# High number of socket descriptor in rmq

Tags: sockets, networking, rabbitmq, microservices, spring-rabbit

We recently had an  issue in our rabbitmq server , where it was unable to accept new connections and dropping those TCP connections .
we didn’t saw any spike in our channels or consumers .

Socket Descriptors(SD) and erlang process shoot up in short span of time causing Rabbit MQ to get stuck and no new connections get established post that.
We do not see any significant increase in channels, connections or consumers to establish a link between the sudden increase in SD and erlang Processes.

RMQ VERSION: 3.7.14
Erlang version: Erlang 21.3.8.1
RMQ running on Kubernetes  as a stateful set .
RMQ erlang process spike .
[image]

Socket used.

[image]

Post restarting the server its working fine , but its resurfacing again .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check server's half-open connections. Seems you can have that kind of a situation if you have an aggressive reconnects from clients side. They create connections, and reconnect again and again.
Also, even if you have the same amount of consumers, there can be increased amount of publishers.
So, my suggestion here - to check logs and metrics on reconnects to rabbitmq.

Comment: Hi nikit , at the time of issue we are not seeing any increase in consumers and channels as compared to the socket descriptors. Added the same in the original question.

Comment: Also how do check the half open connections from the MQ side. As in the RMQ UI i was not seeing any increase in the connections as i mentioned.